# Custom error message within wpcf7_before_send_mail

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I’m using Contact Form 7 and its `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action to interact with an API before sending the email. If the API returns an error, I want to be able to grab that error, display it as an error and prevent the form from being submitted.

I can’t seem to find what I’m looking for anywhere online. The best I can do is use the `mail_sent_ok` message string and display the error within it (which is obviously not the solution).

Basically, the ultimate solution would be to force the form submission to fail.

Anyone else in the same boat?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it was possible at the time you asked your question but the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook has an abort flag that your just have to set to avoid mail to be sent.

for instance in pseudo PHP

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'your_function', 10, 3);
function your_function($form, &$abort, $object){
  $error = 1;
  if($error != 0) {
      $abort = true;
      $object->set_response("An error happened");
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for abort parameter. I posted another answer because for me '$object' parameter is always null. You drove me to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Based on Louise-Philippe's answer, I solved with this code, since $object parameter happends to be always null:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'your_function', 10, 3);
function your_function($form, &$abort, $object){
  $error = 1;
  if($error != 0) {
      $abort = true;
      $msgs = $form->prop('messages');
      $msgs['mail_sent_ng'] = "An error happened"; //<- your custom error message
      $form->set_properties(array('messages' => $msgs));
  }
}
```

Note: it's not `mail_sent_ok` but `mail_sent_ng` so you can have red border as predefined error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if someone might still need this. But you can use the below to do the job.

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$submission->set_response( 'the message' )
```

Comment: You need to add the `$abort = true;` before the `set_response` line so that the error can be sent back. Also, when using the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook it will have the $submission object available to be worked on.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a custom validation with this filter :

```
add_filter("wpcf7_validate", function ($result, $tags) {

    $valid = FALSE; // here you can do your API call to calculate the validation

    if (!$valid) {

        $result->offsetSet(
              "reason"
            , ["your-name" => "error message for this field"]
        );

    }


    return $result;

}, 10, 2);
```

`your-name` must be the name of a existing field of this form.